# get value of particular pic id using jquery ui drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

hello its like i am making a drag and drop system and i want that when i drag and drop a pic it should be deleted but the problem is when many pics are there and even if i drag and drop any random pic the first pic always gets deleted instead of the one which should be deleted. i made a jquery code in which i get the picid, id,and login id thought jquery .attr() and then i break the values with the help if split and then get all the values i want . for each pic the pic id differs but everytime whatever pic i drag and drop using alert i found that its taking values from the very first pic .

my code  i get value throught `var a = $('.plzx').attr('mihref');` but its getting value from the very first pic . can anyone help

```
$(function() {
    // there's the gallery and the trash
    $trash = $("#trash");

    // let the gallery items be draggable
    $("a", ".polaroids").draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: function() {
            $copy = $(this).clone();
            return $copy;
        },
        appendTo: 'body',
        scroll: false
    });
    $("a", ".polaroids").selectable();    

    $trash.droppable({
        accept: ".polaroids a",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var a = $('.plzx').attr('mihref');
            alert(a);
            var parts = a.split("?")[1].split("&");

            var table = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                var pair = parts[i].split('=');
                table[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }    

            var gid = table.id;
         }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it would get the first element that it encounters.
instead, use:

```
$(ui.helper).attr('mihref');
//or
$(event.target).attr('mihref');
```

Answer (score 0):

well i found the answer and i know many would stuck at this so sharing it for all  instead of

```
var a = $('.anyclass').attr('anyattribute');
```

use

```
var dumember=ui.draggable.attr("anyattribute");
```

hope it helps